# Array multiplication in Cuda produce in error

Tags: c++, api, cuda, runtime-error, invalid-argument

I want to multiply two arrays and I have a problem with Cuda RunTime API. There is an error: cuda runtime  API error 11: invalid argument. What is the argument? Help me, please
The code:

```
// includes, system
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>

// includes, project
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cutil_inline.h>
#include <shrQATest.h>

#define SIGNAL_SIZE  8192
#define SIGNAL_COUNT 384

// Complex data type
typedef float2 Complex; 

static __device__ __host__ inline Complex ComplexMul(Complex, Complex);
static __device__ __host__ inline Complex ComplexAdd(Complex );
static __global__ void ComplexPointwiseMA(Complex* , Complex* , Complex* );

// Complex addition 
static __device__ __host__ inline Complex ComplexAdd(Complex a,Complex b)
{
    Complex c;
    c.x = a.x + b.x;
    c.y = a.y + b.y;
    return c;
}

// Complex multiplication
static __device__ __host__ inline Complex ComplexMul(Complex a, Complex b)
{
    Complex c;
    c.x = a.x * b.x - a.y * b.y;
    c.y = a.x * b.y + a.y * b.x;
    return c;
}

// Complex Mul 'n Add function
static __global__ void ComplexPointwiseMA(Complex* mas1, Complex* mas2, Complex*mas_tmp)
{
    const int numThreads = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    const int threadID = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j=0, k=0; 
    Complex c;
    int size=SIGNAL_COUNT*SIGNAL_SIZE;
    for (int i = threadID; i <size; i += numThreads)
    {
        if((i%SIGNAL_SIZE==0)&&(j<SIGNAL_COUNT))
            j++;
        c=ComplexMul(mas1[i], mas2[j]);
        mas_tmp[k]=ComplexAdd(mas_tmp[k],c);
        if(k>=SIGNAL_SIZE-1)
            k=0;
        else
            k++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int threads_per_block=256;
    int blocks_per_grid=16;
    //dim3 dimBlock(SIGNAL_COUNT, SIGNAL_SIZE); // threads 
    //dim3 dimGrid(SIGNAL_COUNT); // 384 blocks in a grid
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float elapsedTime;
    //shrQAStart(argc, argv);
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    // For random
    srand(1001);

    // Allocate host memory for the mass
    Complex* mas_tmp=NULL;
    mas_tmp =new Complex [SIGNAL_COUNT*SIGNAL_SIZE];

    Complex* mas1=NULL;
    mas1 =new Complex [SIGNAL_COUNT*SIGNAL_SIZE];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <SIGNAL_COUNT*SIGNAL_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        mas1[i].x = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        mas1[i].y = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }

    Complex* mas2=NULL;
    mas2 =new Complex [SIGNAL_COUNT];
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < SIGNAL_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        mas2[i].x = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        mas2[i].y = rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }

    // Timer
    cudaEventRecord(start,0);

    // Allocate device memory for mass
    Complex* mastmp_=NULL; // temporary 
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&mastmp_, SIGNAL_SIZE*SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex)));
    Complex* mas1_=NULL; // signal
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&mas1_, SIGNAL_SIZE*SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex)));
    Complex* mas2_=NULL; // coefficient
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMalloc(&mas2_, SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex)));

    // Copy host data to device
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(mas1_, mas1, SIGNAL_SIZE*SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex),    cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(mas2_, mas2, SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // Calling  Mul 'n Add function
    ComplexPointwiseMA<<<blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block>>>(mas1_, mas2_, mastmp_);

    // Check if kernel execution generated and error
    cutilCheckMsg("Kernel execution failed [ ComplexPointwiseMA ]");

    // Copy device memory to host
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(mastmp_, mas_tmp, SIGNAL_SIZE*SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&elapsedTime, start,stop);
    printf("Time %3.10f ms\n", elapsedTime);

    // Free memory  
    free(mas1);
    free(mas2);
    free(mas_tmp);
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);

    cutilSafeCall(cudaFree(mas1_));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaFree(mas2_));
    cutilSafeCall(cudaFree(mastmp_));

    cutilDeviceReset();
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please pay much closer attention to your code formatting in future. You can see tips on the conventions for posting and formatting code in [this meta stackoverflow question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/163653).

Comment: Also, you haven't explained where in the code the error occurs.

Comment: You could use `cublasCgemv()` to do the matrix-vector multiplication to simplify your code and maximize the performance.

Answer (score 2):

The following line in your code will generate the error of `Invalid Argument`.

```
// Copy device memory to host
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(mastmp_, mas_tmp, SIGNAL_SIZE*SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

In the function `cudaMemcpy`, the first argument is the destination pointer and the 2nd argument is the source pointer.
You have specified the flag `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` but the host(destination) and device(source) pointers are interchanged.

You should be doing this (swap the first 2 arguments):

```
cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(mas_tmp, mastmp_,SIGNAL_SIZE*SIGNAL_COUNT*sizeof(Complex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```